linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic error Ubuntu
I've got this problem on my Ubuntu 24.04.
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package list... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating update... Done
The following packages will be removed:
linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic
The following updates have been deferred due to phasing:
apport apport-core-dump-handler apport-gtk evince evince-common
gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gstreamer1.0-packagekit
libevdocument3-4t64 libevview3-3t64 libpackagekit-glib2-18 libudisks2-0
packagekit packagekit-tools python3-apport python3-problem-report udisks2
0 updated, 0 installed, 1 to remove and 17 not updated.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 15.0 MB of disk space will be freed.
Continue? [Y/n] yes
(Reading the database... 246235 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic (6.8.0-48.48)...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-48-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 13: /etc/default/grub: drm.debug=0: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: Error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic (--remove):
installed sub-process package linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic post-removal script returned error status 127
dpkg: too many errors, terminating
Errors occurred while processing:
linux-image-6.8.0-48-generic
The operation was blocked because too many errors occurred.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


The error message is: -
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 13: /etc/default/grub: drm.debug=0: not found

/boot/grub/grub.cfg automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
I suspect you have something wrong in the source file /etc/default/grub which is user configurable. Take a look at line 13 and see if you can identify a problem there.

I have found the solution on that page                                                                             https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1
